# Process.exited wont trigger if windows puts up a popup

Tags: c#, process

In my C# sharp code i try to keep a not so stable scanner program running.
An executable that deals width some hardware. The problem is that the vendor hardware+program is not that stable, it uses socket communication.
But sometimes their executable just crashes.
So i try to detect if its executable is still active, when i "shouldscan".
And relaunch it in case it has exited for some unknown reason.

part of the code:

```
myProcess = new Process();
string pcfile = "C:\\Scanner.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = pcfile;
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myProcess.Exited += (sender, e) =>
{
  // Debug.WriteLine("Process exited with exit code " + myProcess.ExitCode.ToString());
  // MessageBox.Show("Process exited with exit code " + myProcess.ExitCode.ToString());
  if (SynchronousSocketListener.shouldScan == true) myProcess.Start();

            };
myProcess.Start();
```

Most of the times this works works well, but in some situations i get a popup

[image]

Now windows requires a button to be pushed..
Worse usually the program runs in a hidden process, so no one could ever push a botton then. How can i disable that windows hijacks the picks up the failing of that application, i rather have it just simply crash so the exit event can restart it.

Comment: Maybe this link can help: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/disable-program-has-stopped-working-error-dialog-in-windows-server-2008/

Comment: Google "windows disable wer for a program"

Comment: thanks both that seams the right direction, kinda wished it was optional for a process but thats not the case